# How do I SELECT elements using WHERE with another table's record values in WHERE statement?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, join, select, subquery

### Problem summary

Today part of my app crashed, but nothing else stopped with it. I need to find the first and last tracked message ids for each channel during the downtime. I log unix timestamps alongside each message record, so I will be using those to determine which messages were not tracked during this period.

Let's say the downtime started at timestamp `x` and ended at timestamp `y`. I want to return the last tracked message in channel `z` before timestamp `x`, and the first tracked message after timestamp `y`. *I hope that makes sense.*

### Here are my tables

```
mysql> select * from messages limit 5;
+---------+---------+-----------+
| message | channel | timestamp |
+---------+---------+-----------+
| 123     | 456     | 165789921 |
| 124     | 457     | 165789921 |
| 125     | 458     | 165789922 |
| 126     | 459     | 165789922 |
| 127     | 460     | 165789924 |
+---------+---------+-----------+

mysql> explain select * from messages;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | messages | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 211250 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------+

CREATE TABLE messages (
    message VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `channel` VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (message),
    FOREIGN KEY (`channel`) REFERENCES channels (`channel`)
);
```

```
mysql> select * from channels limit 5;
+---------+-----+
| channel | ... |
+---------+-----+
| 456     | ... |
| 457     | ... |
| 458     | ... |
| 459     | ... |
| 460     | ... |
+---------+-----+

mysql> explain select * from channels;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | channels | NULL       | index | NULL          | guild | 74      | NULL | 1434 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+

CREATE TABLE channels (
    `channel` VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(`channel`),
    FOREIGN KEY (guild) REFERENCES guilds (guild)
);
```

### What I've tried

I've tried using a LEFT JOIN with WHERE clauses, but I'm no MySQL expert to say the least. There might be a way to do it this way, I just can't with my current knowledge. The issue I was facing with this approach is, I'm not sure how to access the original channel id for matching in the SELECT query.

***DOES NOT WORK - Obviously, why else would I be here...***

```
SET @min := 1657956885428;
SET @max := 1657966145675;
SELECT * FROM (SELECT channel FROM channels) as channels
LEFT JOIN (SELECT channel, message as downtime_start_after FROM messages WHERE timestamp < @min ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1) AS after USING (`channel`)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT channel, message as downtime_end_before FROM messages WHERE timestamp > @max ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS before USING (`channel`);

+---------+----------+-----------+
| channel | ...after | ...before |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 456     | NULL     | NULL      |
| 457     | 124      | NULL      |
| 458     | NULL     | 130       |
| 459     | NULL     | NULL      |
| 460     | NULL     | NULL      |
+---------+----------+-----------+
```

### Ideal result

Both parameters `after` and `before` should be the message IDs which were tracked last and first respectively. I intend to use these to determine whether a message in a channel may have been within this period.

```
+---------+----------+-----------+
| channel | ...after | ...before |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 456     | 123      | 128       |
| 457     | 124      | 129       |
| 458     | 125      | 130       |
| 459     | 126      | 131       |
| 460     | 127      | 132       |
+---------+----------+-----------+
```

*of course, the data here is just filler*

Thanks in advance. Lmk if I should include any additional information!

### EDIT:

I spent some more time working on a query, and managed to find something which works. I'd be more than glad to hear any advice people have for optimisations.

```
SET @down := 1657956885428;
SELECT * FROM (SELECT channel FROM channels) as channels
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT channel, message as `after` FROM messages WHERE `timestamp` < @down ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC ) as after_messages GROUP BY (`channel`)) as `after` USING (channel)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT channel, message as `before` FROM messages WHERE `timestamp` > @down ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC ) as before_messages GROUP BY (`channel`)) as `before` USING (channel);

+---------+-------+--------+
| channel | after | before |
+---------+-------+--------+
| 456     | 123   | 128    |
| 457     | 124   | 129    |
| 458     | 125   | 130    |
| 459     | 126   | 131    |
| 460     | 127   | 132    |
+---------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Please get rid of the extraneous columns and shorten the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @RickJames. I've made those changes now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the downtime started at timestamp x and ended at timestamp y. I want to return the last tracked message in channel z before timestamp x

Does this achieve that?

```
SELECT ...
    FROM t
    WHERE channel = z
      AND timestamp <= x
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Change three things to get the first item after z, then put them together thus:

```
( SELECT ... x ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... y ... )
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Timestamp looks like a timestamp, why use `TINYTEXT?  Consider` BIGINT`.  And add these indexes:

```
INDEX(timestamp)
INDEX(channel, timestamp)
```

will give you two rows.

**More**

A rewrite of the query you presented; this should run a lot faster:

[code]

```
SELECT  channel, 
    (
        SELECT  message
            FROM  messages
            WHERE  channel = c.channel
              AND  timestamp < @down
            ORDER BY  timestamp DESC
            LIMIT  1 
    ) AS 'after', 
    (
        SELECT  message
            FROM  messages
            WHERE  channel = c.channel
              AND  timestamp > @down
            ORDER BY  timestamp ASC
            LIMIT  1 
    ) AS 'before',
    FROM  channels AS c
    ORDER BY channel  -- you may want this
    ;
```

And, again, `messages` needs `INDEX(channel, timestamp)`.

If there is a message at exactly @down, it will be missed.  Consider changing > to >= or < to <= (but not both).

Comment: That's simple enough. However it doesn't really solve the problem.

There are over a thousand records in the channels table, and I don't intend to do manually input the channel id for each query.

I would like a query which can use the id in each channel record to use in the WHERE clause of a looping?-SELECT query.

I found a way to resolve it - please reference the edit - though I'm pretty sure it's quite inefficient.

Comment: @jayc331 - Thanks for the updates.  You started with a LIMIT 1, but that seems to be gone.  Do you want ONE message on either side?  Or ALL messages on each side?

Comment: Just the two extreme values, so ONE either side. My edit shows the desired result if you wanna refer to that.

Comment: @jayc331 - I added a faster way to write it.

Comment: Fantastic, works like a charm. Thanks for the fast responses.